# Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ uid: '123456' }\" (type Object) at path \"_id\" for model \"ItemBill\"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
uid: { type: String, required: true },
itemName: { type: String, required: true },
itemCode: { type: String, required: true },
itemCount: { type: Number, required: true },
itemPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
units: { type: String, required: true },
});

const AddItem = mongoose.model("ItemBill", itemSchema);

export default AddItem;

const editAddItem = async (req, res) => {
const { uid, itemName, itemCode, itemCount, itemPrice, units } = req.body;
console.log({ uid, itemName, itemCode, itemCount, itemPrice, units });
try {
const editBillData = await AddItem.findByIdAndUpdate(
{ uid },
{ itemName, itemCount, itemPrice, units },
);
if (!editBillData) {
return res.status(404).json({ error: "Item not found." });
}
res.status(200).json(editBillData);
} catch (e) {
res
.status(500)
.json({ msg: "Internal Server Error editAddItem", error: e });
}
};

export { editAddItem };
```

I'm getting error

{
"msg": "Internal Server Error editAddItem",
"error": {
"stringValue": ""{ uid: '123456' }"",
"valueType": "Object",
"kind": "ObjectId",
"value": {
"uid": "123456"
},
"path": "_id",
"reason": {},
"name": "CastError",
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ uid: '123456' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "ItemBill""
}
}

How i fix this error.

Comment: Looks like the data passed in `req.body` is invalid (`"uid" : "{ uid : '123456' }"`).

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake in this find by one it was find by id! so i change this one

**Old**
`AddItem.findByIdAndUpdate`

Change to .

**New**
`AddItem.findOneAndUpdate`